# Check the SharePoint list item level permission using Rest Api

Tags: jquery, sharepoint

As i'm using the SharePoint list , i need to check the user that he has permissions to edit an item or not , and that has to be done using the rest api.
i have tried in different ways by using the doesUserHavePermissions and getUserEffectivePermission . It didn't worked out.

Can anyone of you suggest me the best way to do that.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have you updated your manifest file so your app can have access to the User Profiles and retrieve such information? If your app do not have permissions to the User Profiles it probably would not get the user permissions.

Your manifest should look something like this:
[image]

Where you assign at least read to the User Profiles so the app can get permissions information from the SharePoint services.